# Grey box when running JetBrains Rider on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, java, window-manager, intellij

I am trying to get JetBrains Rider running on my Arch Linux laptop. I already have the suggested fix:

```
~ ❯ echo $_JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING
1
~ ❯
```

However, when I try to run Rider, I still get this:

[image: grey box]

My desktop environment is bspwm with polybar. My `.desktop` file for rofi launcher looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Jetbrains Rider
Exec=/home/j/programs/JetBrains\ Rider-2021.3.3/bin/rider.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

And I am using the Java OpenJDK:

```
~ ❯ archlinux-java status
Available Java environments:
  java-11-openjdk (default)
~ ❯
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it is because when you run from a "Desktop Entry" it is not exporting _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING

What I did was:

1. Create a shell script (runRider.sh)

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1;
> /home/j/programs/JetBrains\ Rider-2021.3.3/bin/rider.sh
> ```

2. And run that script from the Desktop Entry, like so:

> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Name=Jetbrains Rider
> Exec=/home/j/programs/runRider.sh
> Terminal=false
> Type=Application
> ```